# What is the general recommendation for sql server crash recovery from mdf/ldf vs backups for least data loss?

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2019, recovery, disaster-recovery

I'm learning steps to recover from sql server OS or OS disk crash. Assuming the OS or OS disk is corrupted and unrecoverable.

I know that a HA solution like fci or ag is better suited to prevent such issues, but assume there is no fci/ag.

Assume:

1. Sql server crashes at 04:40
2. I have full backups from 1am and subsequent hourly log backups starting from 00:45.
3. I have data and log files intact from the original machine (assuming only the OS or the OS went through an unrecoverable crash)
4. Tail log backup cannot be taken because the OS has crashed and so the server is inaccessible

I have 3 options for recovery after installing the OS and sql server software:

1. Shutdown sql services, Restore master, msdb, ssisdb, and for user databases do the following: Apply full backup from 1am and subsequent 3 log backups which will get me upto 03:45. **Therefore I loose almost 1 hours of data.**
2. Shutdown sql services, restore master, msdb, ssisdb, copy the mdf/ldf files from the previous disk, move them into the new server, attach db. **Therefore I don't loose any data.**
3. Shutdown sql services, replace (not restore, not attach) system dbs master, msdb, ssisdb files; for user dbs - copy the mdf/ldf files from the previous disk, move them into the new server, attach db. **Therefore I don't loose any data.**

What is the recommendation of experienced database professionals on the above approaches?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the actual issue. If your disks are corrupt, then option two and three are risky and may not even be possible. If it's truly an isolated incident that only affected the OS and minimizing data loss is a priority then option number two is a *possibility*.

But you generally just want to have good backups that are taken at a frequency that's tolerable to the amount of data loss within your RPO (Recovery Point Objective). Transaction Log backups can be taken at a much higher frequency than every hour. A lot of people take them every 15, 5, or even 1 minute, depending on their RPO. (I personally take them every 5 minutes.)

I also prefer to store the database backups on a share off of the SQL Server instance's machine, so that they're still accessible should drives become inaccessible due to whatever issue is occuring on the instance's box.

Having proper backups, that are kept decoupled from the server they're taken on, and are routinely checked for corruption is the best way to ensure utmost resiliency of your databases.

Comment: In your 1st paragraph, which option number do you mean is possibility?

Comment: @variable Sorry I meant option number two.

Comment: In option 3 the intention is to make sql server think the previous master is the new master without doing a restore or attach. Is this option out of scope?

Comment: @variable In option 3, you say "*attach db*". I don't believe it's possible to formally attach system databases. Yes, you can just replace the MDF and LDF files of those databases while the instance is offline and it *may* work, but that's a really unsupported way of managing the system databases. The recommended approach is using a backup restore.

Comment: Ok thanks but I didn't say attach for option 3 (for system dbs). I said replace.

Comment: @variable You said replace (which I assumed you meant the MDF and LDF files), and then ended the sentence by saying "*attach db*".

Comment: I meant replace for the system dbs and attach for the user dbs.

Comment: I'm reading that FCI replaces the system and user dbs on node 2 so I'm not sure why you think system db replace is bad?

Comment: @variable In your question you say "*assume there is no fci/ag*", so my answer is in regards to that. It is not recommended, by Microsoft, to manually move or attach (I don't think attaching is actually possible) the system databases to a **different** SQL Server instance, and rather they recommend to [restore from a backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: You are correct that Attach is not possible for master. But replace of mdf/ldf is possible which is what technically fci does so I'm unable to get any reference as to why we must not do it.

Comment: @variable Is it not sufficient that the *why* is because Microsoft recommends not to? FCI is a system that probably does a lot more than just copy the MDF / LDF files over, and was tested thoroughly by Microsoft.